# Is there any way to render an object while standing in it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a first person controller and currently if I walk into a slightly transparent object, it disappears until I walk out of it.

I have a 'water' cube object that is very light blue and transparent, and when I move my camera into third person view then enter the water, my screen turns light blue which is good. In first person mode (which is what I'm trying to figure out), the cube disappears and my screen color remains the same.

I know it has something to do with my camera but even after going through all the features on unity docs and changing a few settings in the inspector, it all remains the same.

Comment: use a shader that supports backface rendering ... though I previously did some under water effects via post-processors which can look way cooler then just rendering the water from within ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments your cube is not visible because the backside of its faces is being culled, meaning they are not rendered. This is not a camera setting but a property of the shader your water cubes material is using.

You could create get a duplicate of the shader your are using where you add `Cull Off` to change this.

Read about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Cull.html).

If you want to go that route you need the source files for your shader. Assuming it is one of the Unity Built in shaders you can get them from the Unity Download archive [here](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive) for your Unity version.

Clipping the camera trough objects is rarely a desired and you should look at a different way of achieving your effect like using a post-processing volume because the "water" would still be a cube and be drawn behind everything in front of its faces.
For example in a FPS type game this would result in the gun not changing color.